# Updated Property Not Reflected On Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `Datagrid` as follows

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" CellStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignedCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding AmountToAllocate, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,  StringFormat='{}{0:#,0.00}'}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Add This Allocation" Command="ac:PICommands.AddAllocation"  />

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

You will see that the `ItemSource` of the Grid is the property `RenewalRows` which is an `ObservableCollection` as follows:-

```
public ObservableCollection<Data.Payment.UnitRenewalsRow> RenewalRows
{
    get
    {
        return renewalRows;
    }
    set
    {
        renewalRows = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RenewalRows");
    }
}
```

SelectedItem is bound to the `SelectedRenewalRow` property as follows:-

```
public Data.Payment.UnitRenewalsRow SelectedRenewalRow
{
    get
    {

        return renewalsRow;
    }
    set
    {
        renewalsRow = value;
        //FullAllocationAmount();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRenewalRow");
    }
}
```

There is a button in the last column which calls a command. The code behind as follows:-

```
private  void Allocate(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ap.AddAnAllocation();
}
```

ap is the `StaticResource` class referred in the `DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllocatePaymentClass}, Path=RenewalRows}”`
The code is as follows:-

```
public void AddAnAllocation()
{

    SelectedRenewalRow.Outstanding = SelectedRenewalRow.Outstanding + SelectedRenewalRow.AmountToAllocate;

    Allocation allocation = new Allocation();
    allocation.Amount = SelectedRenewalRow.AmountToAllocate;
    allocation.PaymentInfo = Payment;
    allocation.RenewalInfo = SelectedRenewalRow;
    allocation.Propref = PropRef;
    allocation.FullAddress = FullAddress;

    Allocations.Add(allocation);
    Payment.Allocations = Allocations;


    //reset
    SelectedRenewalRow.AmountToAllocate = 0;
}
```

My problem is the last line. As soon as the user clicks the button that calls `AddAnAllocation()` I would like the screen to immediately update the selected row in the `DataGrid` with the `AmountToAllocate` Property to show as zero. The property is a field on the items in the `RenewalRows` property shown above. The screen eventually does update but only after the row has been deselected and then reselected and then sometimes even only if a few seconds have gone by.

Any ideas? If you need any further information or code please feel free to ask.

Comment: what does `Data.Payment.UnitRenewalsRow` look like - does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Data.Payment.UnitRenewalsRow is a row in a DataTable which I believe does implement internally INotifyPropertyChanged (am I correct?). Also the RenewalsRow property does implement INotifyPropertyChanged  as shown above. Is there a way I can attach a png file (created using the snipping tool) to show you a screen view of the DataTable from VS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is any help but it seems using DataTables + DataRows may have caused issues with other people in the past.

[Have a look here](http://szymonrozga.net/blog/?p=228)

[and here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/de2d7f68-3ca1-4712-80a3-aa94a14dad77)

Comment: Thank you for this. the article entitled WPFying DataRow seems to be what I need. However, how do I access the row class. When I right click on the datatable in the xsd file in VS2012 and choose View Code it only gives me stubs for the datatable and not the rows as follows:-

namespace PrimaryInsure.Data {
    
    
    public partial class Payment {
        partial class UnitRenewalsDataTable
        {
        }
    }
}
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It should be a partial class - meaning you add another partial class of the same same and namespace into your project and they will be merged into one. see http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22603

Comment: WPFying DataRow did the job! Thank you so much!!